# Import data to MySQL using CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to understand Data Warehousing using the book 'Dimensional Data Warehousing with MySQL'. In Chapter 2 I need to insert the data to a table in MySQL.

I am trying this code

```
TRUNCATE customer_stg;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'customer2.csv'
INTO TABLE customer_stg
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES(
customer_number,
customer_name,
customer_street_address,
customer_zip_code,
customer_city,
customer_state
);
```

I am using lampp on Ubuntu 12.04.2. The file 'customer2.csv' has been copied to the folder '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/dw'.
In MySQL I am using an user 'dwid' with password as 'password'.
The file permissions of the csv file is set to

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql   469 Oct 31  2005 customer2.csv
```

but still I am unable to load the data in the table. The loading is possible from the user 'root'.

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL 5.5 manual page:

> LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been
>   configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with
>   --local-infile=0, LOCAL does not work. See Section 6.1.6, “Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL”.

You should set the option:

> local-infile=1

into your [mysql] entry of my.cnf file or call mysql client with the --local-infile option:

> mysql --local-infile -uroot -pyourpwd yourdbname

You have to be sure that the same parameter is defined into your [mysqld] section too to enable the "local infile" feature server side.

It's a security restriction. I learned this from some other question in stackoverflow, I couldn't find the link, I had the answer saved. Hope this will help.

Comment: I have been using Lampp with phpmyadmin. How do I do this?

Comment: what is size of csv file?

Comment: By the way, phpMyAdmin also supports LOAD DATA (it's one of the dropdown choices)

Comment: [Follow this](http://123techtalk.blogspot.in/2008/08/import-csv-to-sql-using-phpmyadmin.html). Let me know if it helps :)